# How to install private Python package from an AWS S3 repository using Poetry?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, dependencies, python-poetry

I'm using Poetry 1.3.2, created a virtual env with Python 3.8 and now trying to install the dependencies of my project via `poetry install`.

The project has a private dependency which is stored in an AWS S3 bucket repository, so I added the address of this channel via `poetry source add --secondary my-conda-repo s3://my-conda-repo/my-key` (the credentials are in my `~/.aws/credentials`).

In `pyproject.toml` I configured my private dependency as

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
my-utils = { version = "5.0.1", source = "INTERNAL" }
```

When I run `poetry install` I get an error:

```
  • Installing my-utils (5.0.1): Pending...
  • Installing my-utils (5.0.1): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for my-utils (5.0.1)
```

**How can I configure Poetry to read from my S3 repository?**

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there's no easy way to point at an object in S3 (I'm researching the same thing at the moment) as poetry is expecting a pypi server over http. So not a complete answer but here's some suggestions:

### s3pypi

There is the [s3pypi](https://github.com/gorilla-co/s3pypi) project, which has instructions for setting up cloudfront to make a pypi server with an S3 backend. Very neat but might require a lot of networking effort to make sure it's private and secure.

### Code Artifact

If you're all setup with AWS access then I would also recommend the [Code Artifact with Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/using-python.html) service, which offers a full private PyPI repository.

### Local download

Bit more on the hacky side but if you can have a pre-build hook that downloads the files from S3 and then you use:

```ini
my-utils = { path = "path/to/source.tar.gz" }
```

There may be a way to get poetry to run a script before you run update but I've not got there yet.